# Origins of the sweat droplet

Tags: tropes, manga-history

When an anime character is embarrassed, they often draw him/her with a sweat droplet.  Which artist came up with this idea and how did it become so prevalent in anime/manga?

Comment: That seems to be pretty much the same question as: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-did-the-sweatdrop-originate. Is there anything that you're asking that isn't answered in the answer to that question?

Comment: @kuwaly: Mostly, yes.  Except for when it began and with whom.